# Getting values from stdClass Object not working

Tags: php, get

I am trying to get the value of the field `brand` from a `stdClass object` but it does output nothing.

Here is the `stdClass object`:

```
stdClass Object ( [brand] => Tesla [model] => Model Test [title] => 12 Perfect onderhouden [images] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [thumb] => https://images.cadar.io/db5af0f2-5f54-49a7-a4f2-cc8b7cdc5f8b/slider-thumb.jpg [full] => https://images.cadar.io/db5af0f2-5f54-49a7-a4f2-cc8b7cdc5f8b/full.jpg ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [thumb] => https://images.cadar.io/679965e0-0dd2-4932-9ff8-a801d52fcc8f/slider-thumb.jpg [full] => https://images.cadar.io/679965e0-0dd2-4932-9ff8-a801d52fcc8f/full.jpg ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [thumb] => https://images.cadar.io/3f0c7800-42e6-432e-a981-7bef8a689b13/slider-thumb.jpg [full] => https://images.cadar.io/3f0c7800-42e6-432e-a981-7bef8a689b13/full.jpg ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [thumb] => https://images.cadar.io/71319696-cc4a-479d-a5f4-353b7a22ed03/slider-thumb.jpg [full] => https://images.cadar.io/71319696-cc4a-479d-a5f4-353b7a22ed03/full.jpg ) ) [accessoryGroups] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Veiligheid [accessories] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Achteruitrijcamera ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Airbag passagier ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Alarm klasse 1(startblokkering) ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Airbag bestuurder ) ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Interieur [accessories] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Keyless start ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Cruise control ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Stuur verstelbaar ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Boordcomputer ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [name] => 12Volt aansluiting ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Stuurbekrachtiging ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Airco (automatisch) ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Elektrisch verstelbare stoel(en) met geheugen ) ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Exterieur [accessories] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Buitenspiegels verwarmbaar ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Keyless entry ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Trekhaak afneembaar ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Buitenspiegels elektrisch verstelbaar ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Parkeersensor voor en achter ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Grootlichtassistent ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Getint glas ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Parkeer assistent ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Panoramadak ) ) ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Milieu [accessories] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Start/stop systeem ) ) ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Infotainment [accessories] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Android auto ) ) ) )
```

And here is how I am trying to get the output of the `brand` field:

```
$vehicle = $response->data->vehicle ?? null;
print_r($vehicle);
echo $vehicle->brand;
```

The `print_r($vehicle)` function outputs the stdClass Object

The `echo $vehicle->brand` is not working.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: How is it “not working”? Do you get an error then? (That you have proper PHP error reporting enabled, should be a given - if not, do that _now_.) What happens if you try to var_dump the value instead of echoing it?

Comment: @CBroe ; it outputs `string(5) "Tesla"` when using `var_dump`

Comment: So you are saying, `var_dump($vehicle->brand);` works, but `echo $vehicle->brand;` in the exact same place didn’t? That doesn’t make sense, something else must be going on then.